# Can msmdpump be used for connecting to local cubes?

Tags: iis, olap, cube, xmla, msas

I am trying to configure IIS to connect to a local cube(.CUB file) through msmdpump so I can query the local cube using XMLA. I changed msmdpump.ini to look like this:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
    <ServerName>"C:\Adventure Works.cub"</ServerName>
    <SessionTimeout>3600</SessionTimeout>
    <ConnectionPoolSize>100</ConnectionPoolSize>
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

When I send an XMLA request to IIS server I get internal server error (error code 500) with this message: There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Has anyone successfully configured IIS to point to a local cube rather than an MSAS server?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a great way to ask a question.  Upvote.